# Why has Google toolbar stopped working in Firefox 3.6.8?

Tags: firefox, google-toolbar

Yesterday, I noticed that my Google Toolbar has stopped working. The toolbar is still there, but it is completely blank (no buttons or input fields, just a gray strip of nothing). In addition to this, tooltips have stopped working.

If I disable the toolbar, the tooltips return to normal, so that particular problem definitely seems to be a side effect of the toolbar.

I tried disabling all my other add-ons, but that made no difference.

I also tried uninstalling and reinstalling Google Toolbar. That made no difference.

I haven't tried reinstalling the browser, but I'm reluctant to do that unless absolutely necessary.

Am I the only one having this problem? Any ideas how to fix?

Note: I'm running Windows XP SP3. I'm using Google Toolbar version 7.1.20100723W.

Comment: Your edit put this back in the active questions queue.  It's a very old question and I see you got little response.  Were you just cleaning up the title or is this still an unsolved problem?  Surely, you're not still using Firefox 3.6.8?

Comment: Just fixing a typo. Sorry for bumping it up the list.

Comment: Can you do something to update the status?  If the problem still exists, maybe update the question.  If it is no longer a problem, maybe indicate that in the question (might even want to close it if there is no longer a way to verify a solution).  If you found a way to solve it, post an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I had the same problem...

Use "Extension Manager Extended" addon and discover the folder that Google Toolbar is installed. Then uninstall it and so delete that folder. After that, try to reinstall.

If above solution does not work, try exploring c:\documents and settings\your user\application data\google and deleting some folders...

If you use only new tab shortcuts, you can install "New Tab JumpStart" insted of using that awful and evil toolbar :)